# Multiply total number of values in column by value in a different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count all the values in one column and then multiply this number by a value in a different table. So far I have:

```
SELECT CLUB_FEE * COUNT(MEMBER_ID) AS VALUE
FROM CLUB, SUBSCRIPTION
WHERE CLUB_ID = 'CLUB1';
```

This is not working however, can anyone please help?

I also need help doing this for multiple clubs. Is it possible to do it all in one statement for all clubs and then get the average?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(c.CLUB_FEE) * COUNT(MEMBER_ID) AS VALUE
FROM CLUB c JOIN
     SUBSCRIPTION s
     ON c.CLUB_ID = s.CLUB_ID
WHERE c.CLUB_ID = 'CLUB1';
```

You can also write this as:

```
SELECT SUM(c.CLUB_FEE) AS VALUE
FROM CLUB c JOIN
     SUBSCRIPTION s
     ON c.CLUB_ID = s.CLUB_ID
WHERE c.CLUB_ID = 'CLUB1';
```

I thought the first version would be clearer, because the OP specifies `COUNT()` in the question.

If you want it for all clubs that have subscribers:

```
SELECT SUM(c.CLUB_FEE) AS VALUE
FROM CLUB c JOIN
     SUBSCRIPTION s
     ON c.CLUB_ID = s.CLUB_ID
GROUP BY c.CLUB_ID;
```

Comment: Why the MAX on CLUB_FEE? There should be only one CLUB_FEE for each CLUB_ID (otherwise, if there are differentiated fees, the VALUE shouldn't be simply the number of members times the max fee).

Comment: @mathguy . . . Otherwise, it would need a `group by`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Thinking through it - whether the selection of the unique club_fee will be pushed down to the club table... playing with explain plans.

Answer (score 0):

From inspecting the explain plans, it seems the following version may be a bit more efficient (since it avoids a join and uses only one aggregation). If you need this for ALL clubs at the same time, then probably all solutions will have the same "optimizer cost" (they will all do a join at some point).

```
select club_fee * (select count(member_id) from subscription where club_id = 'CLUB1')
from   club
where  club_id = 'CLUB1'
```

So now the only aggregate function is pushed into a subquery and the rest does not need either a join or another aggregate function.

Of course, this only matters if performance is important; it may very well not be.